# Swapping out the center JPanel in a BorderLayout

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a JPanel sitting inside the center position of a BorderLayout of a JFrame.  How can I swap out the current JPanel for a new one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add the component to center and revalidate() the parent container

```
container.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, newPanel);
container.revalidate();
```

Comment: BTW, container.revalidate() should actually be container.validate().

Comment: -1, this solution does not work. It appears to work, but try resizing the frame and the previous panel will now be painted on top of the new panel. This is because of how "Z-Ordering" works in Swing. The proper solution is one of the other two suggestions given, depending on your exact requirement.

Comment: suggest you try it out :) A BorderLayout can only have one component in its center and replaces anything that is already there when you add something.

Comment: @derekerdmann could you explain why it's validate and not revalidate?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something on the lines of:

```
void swapCenterPanel(JFrame frame, JPanel oldPanel, JPanel newPanel) {
    frame.getContentPane().remove(oldPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(newPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
}
```

Comment: You will also need to add revalidate() or validate() to this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Card Layout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which manages this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with no z index issues through trial and error.

lets call x the `JPanel` which has the BorderLayout
lets call y the `Component` which is currently occupying `BorderLayout.Center`
lets call z the `JPanel` to replace in the center position.

```
   x.remove(y);
   x.add(z);
   x.repaint();
   x.revalidate();
```

I found if I tried to remove the existing JPanel through the LayoutManager itself, it doesn't work. Instead if you use the remove method of the JPanel the java doc says it notifies the layouts removeLayoutComponent method and seems to do the trick.